# Can I get FilePond to show previews of loaded local images?

Tags: filepond

I use FilePond to show previously uploaded images with the `load` functionality. The files are visible, however I don't get a preview (which I get when uploading a file).

Should it be possible to show previews for files through `load`?

```
files: [{
    source: " . $profile->profileImage->id . ",
    options: {
        type: 'local',
    }
}],
```

Comment: That is possible, you have to define the `server.load` end point, it should return a file object https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#load

Comment: The load end point now points to a PHP method, returning an image blob. Do I have to create a JS function to put that blob into a File object?

Comment: No that should do the trick

Comment: Hm, then I might return the wrong data. It's PHP readfile() output, with the header set to inline, as mentioned in the docs. I see a filename and a file size, but no preview. Does that ring a bell as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Any ideas as to why the file size and name get displayed, but not the image itself?

Comment: No idea, it should do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-filepond-preview-server-file-fo1k1

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. Turned out I missed a content-type header :S.

Answer (score 4):

First you have to install and register [**File Poster**](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-poster/) and [**File Preview**](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-preview/) plugins and here is the example of how to register it in your code:

```
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
import FilePondPluginFilePoster from 'filepond-plugin-file-poster';
    
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginFilePoster,
);
```

then You have to set the `server.load` property to your server endpoint and add a `metadata` property to your files object which is the link to your image on the server:

```
const pond = FilePond.create(document.querySelector('file'));

pond.server = {
    url: '127.0.0.1:3000/',
    process: 'upload-file',
    revert: null,
    // this is the property you should set in order to render your file using Poster plugin
    load: 'get-file/',
    restore: null,
    fetch: null
};
pond.files = [
    {
        source: iconId,
        options: {
            type: 'local',
            metadata: {
                poster: '127.0.0.1:3000/images/test.jpeg'
            }
        }
    }
];
```

the `source` property is the variable you want to send to your end point which in my case I wanted to send to `/get-file/{imageDbId}`. 
 
In this case it does not matter what your endpoint in the `load` property returns but my guess is, we have to return a file object.